# C++ class member variables interaction

Tags: c++, class, variables, declaration

I have a class with 2 variables. They are public.

I want to initialise them in such a way that one is always a multiple of the other, and when i update the first, the other will automatically update.

In my class declaration:

`

```
public:

Int variable1;
Int variable2 = (10*variable1);
```

`
When I update variable1, i want to check what the updated value of variable2 is, and do some stuff based upon that result.

```
variable1++;
If (variable2 > 10)
{
//Do stuff
}
```

So I know that I could get around this by updating the second variable, but I know there must be a way to have he second variable constantly update. The problem is clearly in the declaration, but "const", or "static", won't help... I don't think. If I could find an eloquent way to phrase the problem, I'm sure i could google the answer. But I can't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just cannot do it like that. Correct way is through encapsulation.

In the example below, just call the getters to get the value (inlined = as fast as a direct access) and you can modify only `variable1`. You could add a `set_variable2` method but it would have little sense.

```
public:
  inline int get_variable1() const { return variable1; }
  inline int get_variable2() const { return variable1*10; }
  inline void set_variable1(int new_value) { variable1=new_value; }

private:
int variable1;
```

Comment: Or in a more general case, `set_variable1()` could modify `variable1`, then call a `private` function that does any work necessary to update `variable2`.

Comment: Ok! If it's not possible that's fine. Basically I am wanting to check that a combination of variables do not take variable2 above a certain amount. I will learn to format it correctly. Thanks everyone for their help!

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't do it... create only one variable and multiply it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to just use a multiple of variable 1 whenever you would use variable 2

for your if statement, use

```
if((variable1 * 10) > 10){
  //do stuff
}
```